# Function repeating constantly

Tags: javascript, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I have almost **no** experience with Javascript, although I've used Unity's UnityScript which is based off Javascript.

In UnityScript, there is `Update()` function which executes the commands in the function every frame of the game. **Is there any way I can do this in vanilla JavaScript?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: You're better off with using [`.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) or this [shim](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) from Paul Irish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setInterval()** executes a functions at regualar interval of time.

**Syntax:**

```
setInterval(methodToBeExec, milliseconds);
```

Try the below code.

```
 yourFunction();

 function yourFunction() {
     alert();
     setInterval(exeFunction, 2000);
 }

 function exeFunction() {
     alert("repeated action");
 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/hNmAj/)